# File descriptor 3 leaked on vgcfgbackup invocation. Parent PID: bash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, cron

I'm using bash script to make backup of ubuntu machine with lvm, and then upload it to google drive, script runs every day via cron, without issues, but log file contains following error:

```
File descriptor 3 (/root/borg.sh) leaked on lvcreate invocation. Parent PID 27827: bash
```

What does this error exactly mean? Is it related to lvcreate/vgcfgbackup or bash script itself? 
I couldn't find any useful information, only that 'leaked on invocation' is probably harmless.

full log with -vvv added to lvcreate and vgcfgbackup:
http://dpaste.com/3FYVAC0

bash script:
http://dpaste.com/30NV1ZH

Comment: Yes, I often seen this due to `cron` working: As *`crond`* run his scripts through pipes for driving to *`sendmail`* when needed, they open some unusual file descriptors (input/ioutput feeders).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man lvm`:

> On invocation, lvm requires that only the standard file descriptors stdin, stdout and stderr are available.  If others are found, they get  closed and messages are issued warning about the leak.  This warning can be suppressed by setting the environment variable LVM_SUPPRESS_FD_WARNINGS.

You're probably using file descriptor 3 in your script. Export the `LVM_SUPPRESS_FD_WARNINGS` environment variable in the script before calling `lvcreate`.

Comment: Yes, or you could [close *unwanted file descriptors* before running LV commands](https://superuser.com/a/1825002/178656).

Answer (score 0):

### My two cents:

Yes! I often seen this due to `cron` working: As *`crond`* (cron daemon) run his scripts through *`pipes`* for driving to `sendmail` when needed, they open some *unusual file descriptors* (input/output feeders).

Tired about this message, I did some tests... So there are some remarks/solutions:

#### 1. Using *`LVM_SUPPRESS_FD_WARNINGS`* environment variable

As [correct answer from bernie](https://superuser.com/a/1469561/178656) recommand, the simpliest solution is
to set environment variable: *`LVM_SUPPRESS_FD_WARNINGS`* as

```
LVM_SUPPRESS_FD_WARNINGS=1 lvs
LVM_SUPPRESS_FD_WARNINGS=1 lvcreate ...
```

or simply:

```
export LVM_SUPPRESS_FD_WARNINGS=1
lvs
lvcreate ...
```

But, there is a way to satisfy LVM before running them!

#### 2. Limit LVM environments to only required *file descriptors*:

Then, for better understanding:

##### Create some usefull FD

```bash
exec {dummyFd}<> <(: -)
```

Usefull for using `read` as a *builtin* sleep, sample replacement for `sleep 1.5`:

```bash
read -ru $dummyFd -t 1.5 _
```

Well now if I `lvs`:

```
# lvs >/dev/null 
File descriptor 10 (pipe:[194609045]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 849375: -bash
```

Trying to run `lvs` without error, by closing *unwanted `FD`* in a subshell:

```bash
(exec {dummyFd}<&-;lvs) >/dev/null
```

will do the job!

##### In a *read* loop:

How to store LVS output into usefull variables? For sample, I do this for
storing *snapshots usage* into an *associative array*:

```bash
declare -Ai lvStat='()'
while read -r lv vg attr size orig prct; do
    case $attr in
        s* ) printf -v prct %.2f ${prct%\%}
             lvStat[$lv/$vg]=${prct/.} ;;
    esac
done < <( exec {dummyFd}>&-; lvs )
```

I use integer to store percent values with two decimal, by simply dropping decimal point. So I have to multiply test values by 100:

```bash
for vol in "${!lvStat[@]}"; do
    (( ${lvStat["$vol"]} > 8000 )) &&
        printf 'Volume %s > 80%%: %8.2f%%\n' "$vol" \
            ${lvStat["$vol"]::-2}.${lvStat["$vol"]: -2}
done
```

##### Overall wrapper closing all *unwanted `FD`*:

Here is a little *wrapper* function that close all opened FD, but not `0`*`STDIN`*, `1`*`STDOUT`* and `2`*`STDERR`*:

```bash
closeFdWrapper4Lv()(
    allFileDescriptors=(/dev/fd/*)
    for fileDescriptor in ${allFileDescriptors[@]##*/}; do
        case $fileDescriptor in
            0|1|2 ) ;;
            *     ) exec {fileDescriptor}>&- ;;
        esac
    done
    "$@"
)
```

Care about ***parentheses*** around function instead of regular ***curly braces***!!!

Then you could run:

```bash
closeFdWrapper4Lv lvs
closeFdWrapper4Lv lvcreate ...
```

And still could use your openned *file descriptor*:

```bash
read -ru $dummyFd -t 1.5 _
```